# Trying to place a separator in the middle of 4 diffs

Tags: html, css, position, pseudo-element

i am trying to place a separator element directly in the center of 4 divs, somehow the percentage of the position refers to the width/height of the element itself and not the position within its parent container.

Codepen : http://codepen.io/HendrikEng/pen/ObyLKG

HTML:

```
<section>
    <div class="c-connector-service"></div>
    <div class="c-service">
        <div class="c-service-item">
          loremipsum lalala
        </div>
       <div class="c-service-item">
          loremipsum lalala
        </div>
       <div class="c-service-item">
          loremipsum lalala
        </div>
       <div class="c-service-item">
          loremipsum lalala
        </div>    
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.c-service {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.c-service-item {
  width: 41.66667%;
  float: left;
}

.c-service-item {
  background: pink;
  min-height: 30.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
.c-service-item:nth-of-type(odd) {
  border-right: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}
.c-service-item:nth-of-type(odd) {
  border-right: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}
.c-service-item:nth-of-type(even) {
  border-left: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  margin-left: -1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

.c-connector-service {
  position: relative;
}

.c-connector-service::after {
  background: green;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

Comment: So, you want the green pseudo element centered in the middle of the 4 divs?

Comment: Yes directly centered on the cross

Comment: Is there a reason you have the pseudo element on on `.c-connector-service` instead of `c-service`?

Comment: i thought i would have to gibe the whole connector element a new class, thats also because i would like to reuse the connector element in different sections of the site without changing the css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `<div class="c-connector-service"></div>` element, give the `c-service` `position: relative` and use the same left value on the pseudo as the width given to the `c-service-item`

```css
.c-service {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.c-service-item {
  width: 41.66667%;
  float: left;
  background: pink;
  min-height: 30.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
.c-service-item:nth-of-type(odd) {
  border-right: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}
.c-service-item:nth-of-type(odd) {
  border-right: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}
.c-service-item:nth-of-type(even) {
  border-left: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  margin-left: -1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}
.c-service::after {
  background: green;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 41.66667%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="c-service">
        <div class="c-service-item">
          loremipsum lalala
        </div>
       <div class="c-service-item">
          loremipsum lalala
        </div>
       <div class="c-service-item">
          loremipsum lalala
        </div>
       <div class="c-service-item">
          loremipsum lalala
        </div>    
    </div>
</section>
```